# Git stuck on push, pull, clone, everything

Tags: git, github, ssh

It's a few days that whenever I try to push a commit to the remote branch, pull, clone with ssh (http clone works fine): it just gets stuck, without any error message or so on, nothing, just stuck

I tried reinstalling Git, removing and purging it and reinstalling, removing the `.gitconfig` folder, removing the ssh key and creating a new one as explained [here](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account), but nothing worked...

After purging and removing `.gitconfig` and changing the key it achieved to do ONE ssh clone and ONE push, then again it got stuck...

What can be the cause of this problem? I'm desperate :(
(I'm running Kubuntu 22.04 and trying to push on GitHub)

thanks in advance!

EDIT: okay perhaps I finally understood what the problem is: my router. If I connect to my mobile hotspot everything works just fine...
EDIT 2: if I connect with the ethernet cable it has this problem, but if I try to connect to the wifi of the same exact router it works fine...

is there a way to resolve this problem without changing the router?

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 isn't out yet, so I doubt Kubuntu 22.04 is either. Are you using a daily build? Or is that a typo?

Comment: In any case, please add [`-v` / `--verbose`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt--v) to one of the commands you are running to get more information about what's happening.

Comment: @Chris I'm using a daily build downloaded from [here](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/daily-live/20220312/) but that's not the problem because I tried booting into a Fedora live usb, I created an ssh key and tried to clone and again nothing worked...

Comment: @Chris if I just add the verbose flag nothing changes, not a single output more than before, stuck at the same point... instead if I try running `env GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git clone --verbose git@github.com:tubbadu/Scriptinator.git` this is the [output](https://pastebin.com/KXxe8JT8)

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the router?

Comment: @JohnZwinck just tried, but nothing changed... anyway I noticed that if I connect with the ethernet cable it gets stuck, but if I connect to the wifi of the same router it works fine... what can be the problem?

Comment: Bad router.  Replace it.

Comment: I had the same issue. It was because I was using the free wifi at our school! Eduroam works fine. It wasted half of my day trying to rotate ssh keys and digging deep into git config stuff!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally found a workaround: running

```
sudo /sbin/iptables -A OUTPUT -t mangle -p tcp --dport 22 -j TOS --set-tos 0x00
```

fixes the problem for the current session